# Are impacts in outer space more powerful than on Earth?

Tags: energy, acoustics, collision, vacuum, atmospheric-science

Is an impact less destructive on Earth than on other planets with no atmosphere, given that the momenta, factors like the line of impact are identical in both cases? If yes, then is it because there is no sound to carry away some of the energy?

Comment: I guess you by "impact" mean reaching the ground. The atmosphere slows down an incoming object. The friction / drag with the atmosphere will often erode the object before reaching the ground. Earth is "struck" all the time by space objects that never reach the ground.

Comment: Do you mean "impacts" like in @Steeven 's comment, or are you just asking about collisions between different objects?

Comment: Yeah collision.